# Prevent reorder of first column in tableview?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a tableview with several columns that allow reordering. The table is a list of songs, each row representing a song.  The first column (left-most) is used to display an icon next to a row when it's "active" (song is playing).  I would like to prevent any columns from being reordered to the left of it and always keep it as the first column in the table.

My theory is to somehow intercept the reordering actions and if a column tries to insert itself as column 0, deny the change. But I can't figure how to do it, or at least find which methods I'd need to use.  That was my logic for accomplishing this in Swing anyways.

I've searched the internet and only solutions I've found were for disabling reordering of all columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution provided by the JavaFx,but a workaround can be implemented to prevent a column to be reordered.

You can prevent it visually, i mean if the first column is in the moved list simply put it back to the position where you want to see it, it happens so quickly the user doesn`t even notice it.

Here is a simple code you can check:

`.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="stackoverflow.reorder.Controller">
    <TableView fx:id="table">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="first" text="1"/>
            <TableColumn text="2"/>
            <TableColumn text="3"/>
            <TableColumn text="4"/>
            <TableColumn text="5"/>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView<Object> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Object, String> first;

    private ListChangeListener<? super TableColumn<Object, ?>> columnReorderListener = c -> {
        if (c.next()) {
            if (c.getAddedSubList().contains(first)) {
                table.getColumns().removeListener(listener());
                table.getColumns().remove(first);
                table.getColumns().add(0, first);
                table.getColumns().addListener(listener());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        // Its deprecated!!!
        first.impl_setReorderable(false);

        table.getColumns().addListener(columnReorderListener);
    }

    private ListChangeListener<? super TableColumn<Object, ?>> listener() {
        return columnReorderListener;
    }

}
```

There is the deprecated method which prevents the column itself to be draggable, but it doesn't to any other column be dragged to its position. For that is the listener.